# building java project using ANT utility

Tags: ant, jar, building

I am using an ANT script to build the jars of the projects that I have in my eclipse workspace. The command that I use is `ant -f <build_file.xml>`

I want to build the projects using the ant script only (at the moment I am using eclipse for the this). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why can't you just run that command from the command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and [ANT Tutorial](http://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/docs/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/ant/ant.html) would be the best places to start.

Comment: i am using the above command only for creating jars, but i also want  the projects to get compiled somehow..??

Answer (score 3):

This will compile the Java files in **my_prj/src** to **my_prj/classes** using the jars in **my_prj/lib**.

```
<javac srcdir="my_prj/src"
    destdir="my_prj/classes"
    debug="on">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="my_prj/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Ant build script will contain several targets that you can invoke.  From the command line use the `-p` switch to list those that are available along with their descriptions:

```
ant -f mybuildfile.xml -p
```

You can then invoke one of the listed targets:

```
ant -f mybuildfile.xml sometarget
```

[Note: the `-f` is not necessary if the build file is called `build.xml`, as is the usual convention]